# Setting up router as a DHCP server on packet tracer for a 2811 router and 3 hosts

Tags: cisco-ios, packet-tracer

I am trying a configure a 2811 Cisco router on packet tracer to be a DHCP server for 3 hosts.

Here is the running config I have as of now:

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 657 bytes
!
version 12.4
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname r1
!
!
!
!
!
ip dhcp pool stackexchange
 network 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.0.1
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
```

The configuration is as suggested by @Andrey Prokhorov but now I found no "lease" command.

[image]

I must be able to have the DHCP service working on all 3 host.

[image]

Comment: Resource recommendations are explicitly off topic here. You can rephrase your question and show us what configuration you've tried and what problems you ran into. Then the question may be on topic and people may be able to help you.

Comment: You got it... I will work on that

Comment: **lease** parameter can be absent in PacketTracer, as it's simplified version of real Cisco IOS

Comment: @AndreyProkhorov , is the lease parameter necessary to complete the setup?

Comment: @AzaamAlfi-PSM no, it's not necessary

Comment: @AndreyProkhorov neither is the "domain-name" parameter as it also doesn't exist if you noticed?

Comment: you should consider setting up gns3 to do these cisco labs!

Comment: @allwynmasc I installed it on my opensuse and port 3080 on 127.0.0.1 gives (connection refused)

Comment: @AzaamAlfi-PSM please use the gns3 forums for that. Off topic discussions won't be allowed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets assume you want to deliver IP addresses to your interface Gi0/0 (addr 192.168.0.1) network 192.168.0.0/24, also you have DNS server 192.168.0.5. Then you should define DHCP pool with options:

```
service dhcp
ip dhcp pool NET_192.168.0.0
 network 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.0.1
 dns-server 192.168.0.5
 lease 7
 domain-name net.local
```

This will enable DHCP service for your 192.168.0.0/24 network with lease time for each address in 7 days.

Also, you can exclude IP addresses from distributed scope by entering command:

```
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.10
```

This will prevent issuance of addresses 192.168.0.1 thru 192.168.0.10. You can add many of that entries. Exclude records can consist of only one address:

```
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.0.200
```

You can find more about configuring DHCP server in Cisco IOS here - [Configuring DHCP](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipaddr_dhcp/configuration/12-4t/dhcp-12-4t-book/config-dhcp-server.html)

Comment: Andrey, I do not have a DNS server in my packet tracer setup...

Comment: @AzaamAlfi-PSM, ok, just don't specify dns-server name/address if you don't need it.